# Pausing app store updates in Mojave

Tags: mac-appstore, mojave

On my less-than-ideal internet, updates such as XCode take many hours to download, and basic browsing (e.g. stack exchange) slows to a crawl while they're loading. I'd like to be able to pause the download and resume it later.

I know I can **cancel** downloads by pressing the download ring in the App Store app, but I can't find any way to pause downloads in a way which can be resumed later without re-downloading the whole thing. The internet leads me to believe that this used to be possible by right-clicking the app's icon in the dock and selecting 'pause', but this doesn't appear in Mojave (neither on the app being downloaded nor on the app store itself).

What do I need to do to pause an update?

Comment: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254173/88313) doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @fsb ah, yes; it does. Somehow I missed that in my searches. Thanks.