# Why Xcode is downloading from the beginning ,if downloading gets failed?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an Question that just want to clarify that Xcode is downloading from the beginning if the downloading gets failed. I am trying to download Xcode 10.1. It gets downloaded 75% if their must be an network issue,downloading gets failed and it start downloading from the beginning ,Here my question is why its doesn't start where it leaves.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Care to elaborate a bit on the “downloading gets failed and it starts downloading from the beginning” part? What is the error message you are getting? Does the download restart without your intervention, or does it depend on any action on your side? Do you see the failed download in `/Applications` (similar to what the screenshot in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337475 shows)?

Comment: Hi synoli, I doesn't get any error message ,If their must be an network issues means it stop the downloading and then I again downloading the Xcode from the beginning this is happened two to three times. (similar to https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU2sm.png )